# Emacs: query-replace prepend text to the found string

Tags: regular-expression, emacs, replace

The scenario is that I am trying to append a new class to all the style declrations in my css file.

So

```
.oldclass{
  float : left;
}
```

should change to

```
.newclass .oldclass{
  float : left;
}
```

The same should apply for all the style declarations in the file as well.

Comment: FYI, there is a new emacs.stackexchange.com site, where you can ask emacs questions if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
M-x query-replace-regexp RET
\(^.*{$\) RET
.newclass \1 RET
```

The actual regexp I am using for matching is `^.*{$` to match full lines the end with a `{` so the I can prepend the new class.

It is enclosed within `\(` and `\)` so that the captured group can be reused in the Replace pattern.

In the replace pattern we use `\1` to refer to the matched group.